# Counting number of times instance appears before switch in PANDAS Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like so  which records the type of an IP at a specific time.

```
IP   Time                 Type  
101  2018-10-16 01:07:11  A     
101  2018-10-16 01:08:34  A     
101  2018-10-16 02:54:11  B     
101  2018-10-16 14:07:39  A     
102  2018-10-17 01:09:10  A     
102  2018-10-17 01:38:24  A     
102  2018-10-17 02:44:10  A     
102  2018-10-17 14:17:40  C
```

How can I create a new column `TimeCount` which keeps track of the number of times an IP appears before it switches to a new type?

expected output is shown below:

```
IP   Time                 Type  TimeCount
101  2018-10-16 01:07:11  A     2
101  2018-10-16 01:08:34  A     2
101  2018-10-16 02:54:11  B     1
101  2018-10-16 14:07:39  A     1
102  2018-10-17 01:09:10  A     3
102  2018-10-17 01:38:24  A     3
102  2018-10-17 02:44:10  A     3
102  2018-10-17 14:17:40  C     1
```

I'm thinking I should be using `shift()` but not sure how to apply it in pandas. If it never switches just keep the count of how many times it appears as the last type.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `groupby` with `cumsum` create the key, then do the `transform`

```
s = df.groupby('IP')['Type'].apply(lambda x : x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum())
df['new'] = df['Type'].groupby([df['IP'],s]).transform('count')
df
             IP      Time Type  new
101  2018-10-16  01:07:11    A    2
101  2018-10-16  01:08:34    A    2
101  2018-10-16  02:54:11    B    1
101  2018-10-16  14:07:39    A    1
102  2018-10-17  01:09:10    A    3
102  2018-10-17  01:38:24    A    3
102  2018-10-17  02:44:10    A    3
102  2018-10-17  14:17:40    C    1
```